# C passing array to function to modify array

Tags: arrays, c

I am learning C and I have a bit of a basic problem. I am using C:How To Program by Deitel and Deitel 8th Edition. I modified the code in Fig 6.13 a little bit to create an array and then pass it to a function, modifyArray to multiply array values by two and then print both arrays. The code in the book produces the expected result, however my code produces the original array but the modified array is wrong. Please help I am stuck.

Here is the code and result:

```
// programm to pass arras and individual array elements to functions
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#define SIZE 5                          // define system constant

int main(void)
{
    int a[SIZE];

    puts("Effects of passing the entire array by reference:\n\n" "The values of the original array are:");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        a[SIZE] = i;
        printf("%3d\n", a[SIZE]);
    }
    puts("");                           // outputs blank line
    puts("The values of the modified array are:");
    void modifyArray(int b[], size_t size);

    modifyArray(a, SIZE);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        printf("%3d\n", a[i]);
    }
}

void modifyArray(int b[], size_t size)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
        b[j] = j *= 2;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Effects of passing the entire array by reference:

The values of the original array are:
  0
  1
  2
  3
  4

The values of the modified array are:
  0
  0
  2
  0
  8
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.047 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Expected Result:

modified values should be:

```
0
2
4
6
8
```

Comment: Please format and indent your code if you expect others to read it.

Comment: `a [SIZE]=i;`? That's not correct. Same indexing problem when you print the value in the same loop. By using an out-of-bounds index, your program will experience *undefined behavior*.

Comment: OT: The `modifyArray` function gets a `size` argument. It should probably use that for the array size.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this, how should I format and indent?

Comment: That's addressed by any programming learning material. Now someone did it for you this time...

Comment: Thanks Some programmer dude for the quick help. I fixed the indexing problem as you said, it works now. Really great to get quick help.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the great in depth help. Great site, quick help, I am happy. Hope to see again in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few issues ...

1. The loop in `main` that sets up the array has UB (undefined behavior) because doing `a[SIZE] = i;` accesses *only* a single array element and that is one *beyond* the end of the array.
2. The loop in `ModifyArray` does: `b[j] = j *= 2;` This has the progression for `j` of 0,2,6 instead of 0,1,2,3,4 so it goes beyond the end of the array (again, UB). It should just be: `b[j] *= 2;`
3. In `ModifyArray`, the loop used `SIZE` instead of `size` (the argument).

---

Your original code in (2) is a bit tricky. As you wrote it, it is the equivalent of:

```
j *= 2;
b[j] = j;
```

**Edit:**

After thinking about this a bit, the original code ...

```
b[j] = j *= 2;
```

... May be [or may not be] a sequence point violation [another form of UB]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

From that page:

> With C11 and C++11, usage of the term sequence point has been replaced by sequencing. There are three possibilities:
>
> 1. An expression's evaluation can be sequenced before that of another expression, or equivalently the other expression's evaluation is sequenced after that of the first.
> 2. The expressions' evaluation is indeterminately sequenced, meaning one is sequenced before the other, but which is unspecified.
> 3. The expressions' evaluation is unsequenced.

In other words, whether the compiler chooses the above "equivalent" code or the following "equivalent" code is one of the three possibilities mentioned.

That is, the value of `j` used when calculating the address of `b[j]` could be the value either before or after the changed value of `j` from `j *= 2`.

1. The above code uses the *changed* value of `j` [which is what *my* compiler did].
2. Or, the compiler could use the *original/unchanged* value of `j` when calculating the address of `b[j]`. It is equivalent to the following:

```
b[j] = j;
j *= 2;
```

IMO ...

1. Loosely, an assignment is `<lvalue> = <rvalue>;`
2. Trying to determine which of the three possibilities from the wikipedia page (nee the ISO C/C++ specs) will actually occur can lead to premature brain damage ;-)
3. It's best to avoid such situations altogether by never using a variable in an `<lvalue>` that is modified in the `<rvalue>` (or vice-versa).

---

Here is the corrected code. It is annotated with the bugs and fixes.

```
// programm to pass arras and individual array elements to functions
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define SIZE 5                          // define system constant

void modifyArray(int b[], size_t size);

int
main(void)
{
    int a[SIZE];

    puts("Effects of passing the entire array by reference:\n\n"
        "The values of the original array are:");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
// NOTE/BUG: this is UB (undefined behavior) because a[SIZE] is one beyond the
// end. And, we're only setting up a single element of the array (and, again,
// it's beyond the end)
#if 0
        a[SIZE] = i;
        printf("%3d\n", a[SIZE]);
#else
        a[i] = i;
        printf("%3d\n", a[i]);
#endif
    }
    puts("");                           // outputs blank line
    puts("The values of the modified array are:");

    modifyArray(a, SIZE);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        printf("%3d\n", a[i]);
    }
}

void
modifyArray(int b[], size_t size)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
// NOTE/BUG: this is UB (undefined behavior) because it exceeds the bounds of
// the array j will be: 0,2,6 instead of 0,1,2,3,4
#if 0
        b[j] = j *= 2;
        printf("%d j=%d\n",b[j],j);
#else
        b[j] *= 2;
#endif
    }
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

Here is the program output:

```
Effects of passing the entire array by reference:

The values of the original array are:
  0
  1
  2
  3
  4

The values of the modified array are:
  0
  2
  4
  6
  8
```

---

Here is the fully cleaned up code:

```
// programm to pass arras and individual array elements to functions
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define SIZE 5                          // define system constant

void modifyArray(int b[], size_t size);

int
main(void)
{
    int a[SIZE];

    puts("Effects of passing the entire array by reference:\n\n"
        "The values of the original array are:");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        a[i] = i;
        printf("%3d\n", a[i]);
    }
    puts("");                           // outputs blank line
    puts("The values of the modified array are:");

    modifyArray(a, SIZE);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        printf("%3d\n", a[i]);
    }
}

void
modifyArray(int b[], size_t size)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
        b[j] *= 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

- When declaring an array of `SIZE` number of items in C, you do write `int a[SIZE];`. Similar syntax is used when accessing the array, but array indexing in C starts counting at item zero. Therefore `a[SIZE] = i;` is wrong, it writes one item out of bounds of the array.

  Probably you actually wanted to do `a[i] = i;`, to create an array like `{ 0,1,2,3,4 }`.
- `void modifyArray(int b[], size_t size);` You shouldn't write this function prototype declaration in the middle of main(). Best practice is to always write it outside any function, somewhere at the top of the file. Otherwise no other function except main() will know of the declaration. Plus other programmers will find function declarations inside function bodies weird - it is valid C but not common style.
- `for (size_t j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)` should be `for (size_t j = 0; j < size; ++j)`.
- `b[j] = j *= 2;` is wrong, it should just be `b[j] = j * 2;`

Additional tips & tricks:

- You could alternatively declare and define the function as `void modifyArray(size_t size, int b[size])` as long as the size argument sits left of the array. This gives self-documenting code and slightly better type safety in some situations.